# Structural Objective C Questions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, delegates

I got a few questions about Objective-C structure. I think I can not figure out the entire structure.

Am setting up connection to the server. Using FacebookSDK and ASIHTTPRequest and SBJSon. I use almost in all classes. FacebookSDK appDelegate used to. I use the same functions is too. For example, take a different user profile.

1. Do I have to collect one class of functions of Request? How do I do?
2. In terms of performance, whether programmatically or xib files do I use?

Comment: xib files are theoretically slower I believe.. but the impact of that is so low that you won't notice that even on the slowest iDevices. Just use multiple xibs and not everything in 1 xib and it will be fine

Answer (score 0):

Your performance is the most important. XIB files are almost always going to take you less time to create and debug. I guarantee you that talking to the server is going to take far more run time than loading objects from a .xib.

Comment: Thank you very much for giving reply. I guess some things on to work with programmatically or xib is not clear. May vary depending on the situation. But in the words of @Antwan van Houdt 's not much difference I guess. So what do you think I use the same function by defining each class separately?